# Integrate between Shelly and Telegram via Webhook

Tags: curl, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, shelly

I have tried to integrate between [Shelly](https://www.shelly.cloud/en) and Telegram.

In Telegram there is an option called [webhook](https://%EF%BB%BFhttps://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks) that mean , if Telegram bot received an message that message will automatically move to another server :

To open my Shelly relay I can send a POST ( [doc](https://shelly-api-docs.shelly.cloud/cloud-control-api/communication/) ):

```
curl -X POST https://shelly-54-eu.shelly.cloud/device/relay/control -d "channel=0&turn=on&id=<Shelly_id>&auth_key=<Shelly_auth_key>"
```

I tried to implement with wehbook a redirection for Shelly cloud , so when my telegram bot received an message my Shelly will open the relay.

I have tried set set the webhook like that :

```
curl -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot<telegam_bot_token>/setWebhook --data-urlencode "url=https://shelly-54-eu.shelly.cloud/device/relay/control?channel=0&turn=on&id=<Shelly_id>&auth_key=<Shelly_auth_key>"
```

But When I watch at getWebhookInfo URL :
`https://api.telegram.org/bot<Tlegram_token>/getWebhookInfo`:
I saw :

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://shelly-54-eu.shelly.cloud/device/relay/control?channel=0&turn=on&id=<Shelly_id>&auth_key=<Shelly_auth_key>","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":5,"last_error_date":1670102630,"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 401 Unauthorized","max_connections":40,"ip_address":"<Shelly_ip>"}}
```

.

If I replace `--data-urlencode` with `-d` :

```
curl -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot<telegam_bot_token>/setWebhook -d "url=https://shelly-54-eu.shelly.cloud/device/relay/control?channel=0&turn=on&id=<Shelly_id>&auth_key=<Shelly_auth_key>"
```

So `https://api.telegram.org/bot<Tlegram_token>/getWebhookInfo` return

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://shelly-54-eu.shelly.cloud/device/relay/control?channel=0","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":1,"last_error_date":1670263360,"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 401 Unauthorized","max_connections":40,"ip_address":"<Shelly_ip>"}}
```

Apparently the problem is that Shelly server expected to get  `channel=0&turn=on&id=<Shelly_id>&auth_key=<Shelly_auth_key>` as "data" and not through URL ,

Is there any way to pass this data using Telegram webhook?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with Shelly server expecting the parameters in data and not in url. The response from the `getWebhookInfo` method clearly tells you that the server returned `401 Unauthorized` response, which means parameters may be not correct. Are `auth_key`, `id` and `channel` correct? Did you test it outside of Telegram?

Comment: Wait, I may be wrong. The way to test where is the problem, you can use `curl` to communicate with the shelly server using two different commands. Try to use curl with `-d` flag and then with `--data-urlencode` flag. If `-d` gives you success response and `--data-urlencode` gives you error response, you'll know that shelly expects data as "form data" and not in url. Which, I am afraid, Telegram webhook can't do.

Comment: @druskacik I have update my post with how I replaced `--data-urlencode` with `-d`

Comment: I meant, try to use `curl` to communicate with shelly server, with `-d` flag and then with `--data-urlencode` flag. Does `curl -X POST https://shelly-54-eu.shelly.cloud/device/relay/control --data-urlencode "channel=0&turn=on&id=<Shelly_id>&auth_key=<Shelly_auth_key>"` work? If not, shelly can't parse arguments from the url.